# More frontend builds at the same time with azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this build pipeline in Azure DevOps:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - frontend

pool:
  name: Default

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 16.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 16.x
    checkLatest: true

#1
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install global'
  inputs:
    command: install
    workingDir: frontend
    verbose: true

#2
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install angular global'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: frontend
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli@latest'

#3
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm link'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: frontend
    verbose: false
    customCommand: link

#4
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: frontend
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build-dynamic'

#5
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive app'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'frontend/dist/dashboard'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App.zip'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App.zip'
```

So far, so good. But now I have in Azure DevOps more frontend folders (e.g. frontend1,frontend2,frontend3). And I want to create separate builds from all these folders .

Is there any way to create some generic pipeline that would run all these steps for every from all mentioned folders (frontend1,frontend2,frontend3) ? And that would be able to read frontend names directly from repository ?

My idea is replace steps #1 to #5 with PowerShell script, assign list of folders with frontends to array and afterwards do all these steps for every folder separately. And subsequently publish all these builds with `PublishBuildArtifacts` pipeline command. But `PublishBuildArtifacts` doesn't support Wildcards what is difficulty for my plan.

Exists there some other or more elegant way how solve this task ? Thanks so much for any clue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, you need to run all npm steps for every from all mentioned folders (frontend1,frontend2,frontend3).

To meet your requirement, we can refer to the following steps:

Step1: use PowerShell script to get the list of the folders. Then we can save it   in variables/parameters.

Step2: use the [Each expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) in YAML pipeline to loop all folders and run all steps for each folder.

Since setting variables in PowerShell needs to be done at runtime, and each expression needs to read the value at compile time, I suggest that it can be divided into two Pipelines to implement it.

One Pipeline is used to get the folder names list and use Rest API to trigger Pipeline with the requirement folder lists parameters. The other pipeline will use each expression to split the parameters to loop each folder name and run all steps.

Here is an example:

Pipeline One:

```
stages:
  - stage: StageA
    displayName: "Stage A"
    jobs:
      - job: StageA
        steps:
          - checkout: self

          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                  [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrlst = @(
                    $(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path '$(build.sourcesdirectory)' | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
                  )
                  $token = "$(pat)"      
                  $url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineid}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
                  
                  $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
                  
                  $JSON = "
                  {
                    
                  
                  
                    `"resources`": {
                      `"repositories`": {
                        `"self`": {
                          `"ref`": `"refs/heads/master`"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    `"templateParameters`": {
                      `"folderlist`":`"$arrlst`"
                    },
                  
                  
                  
                  }"
                  
                  
                  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Pipeline Two:

```
parameters:
  - name: folderlist
    type: string

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 16.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 16.x
    checkLatest: true
- ${{ each folder in split(parameters.folderlist, ' ')}}:
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install global'
    inputs:
      command: install
      workingDir: ${{folder}}
      verbose: true

  #2
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install angular global'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      workingDir: ${{folder}}
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli@latest'

  #3
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm link'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      workingDir: ${{folder}}
      verbose: false
      customCommand: link

  #4
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm custom'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      workingDir: ${{folder}}
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'run build-dynamic'

  #5
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive app'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: ' ${{folder}}/dist/dashboard'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App_${{folder}}.zip'


  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App_${{folder}}.zip'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It looks promising. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: It is running for me ! Only I change `"ref`": `"refs/heads/master`"  to  `"refName`": `"refs/heads/develop`" . Thank you and thank you for patience !

Comment: @LDonSOvrfw Glad to know that it can work for you.!

Comment: Please, does there exist some way, how use in first part of the second pipeline full folder name ( {{folder}} = "frontend-170"} and in second part of this pipeline only extension of {{folder}}, what is "-170" or "" for only "frontend". What means, modify (e.g. with PowerShell) {{folder}} parameter during the pipeline flow. Thank you for your answer !